# Yii2: sum of a column on filtered values in Gridview

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

I can sum a column in gridview using the below code:

```
<?php
$command = Yii::$app->db->createCommand("SELECT sum(net_total) FROM estimate");
$sum = $command->queryScalar();
echo 'Total ='. $sum;
?>
```

I have a column in DB as `discharge_date`(which is date & Time field) and I want to change the sum on filter on this column. That is if filtered data show five records, then I want the sum for only those five records.
Thanks.

**updates as per the answer**

The code is like this:

```
$query = app\models\Estimate::find();
$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $query,
            ]);
$ids = [];
foreach($dataProvider as $i => $model) {
    $ids[] = $model->id;}

$command = Yii::$app->db->createCommand("SELECT sum(net_total) FROM estimate WHERE `id` IN ('.implode(',',$ids).')"); // please use a prepared statement instead, just a proof of concept

$sum = $command->queryScalar();
echo $sum;
```

Now I am getting the error on line
`$ids[] = $model->id;}` as `Getting unknown property: yii\db\ActiveQuery::id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try adding this query to the ActiveDataprovider directly? Specifying additional query parts is possible as explained [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-output-data-providers.html), that should be a possible solution. Alternatively you could try to extract the IDs from the ActiveDataprovider for the results and use them to modify your secondary query.

Example for the second approach:

```
// You should make sure that the same parameters are passed to
// the GridView's ActiveDataProvider and the Model's find() function
$idQuery = Estimate::find()->all();

$ids = [];
foreach ($idQuery as $i => $model) {
    $ids[] = $model['id'];
}

$command = Yii::$app->db->createCommand('SELECT sum(net_total) FROM estimate WHERE `id` IN ('.implode(',',$ids).')'); // please use a prepared statement instead, just a proof of concept
$sum = $command->queryScalar();
```

Comment: Hi Nikolas what is `$copyofADP = /*....*/` what I should replace this with. Thanks.

Comment: The original ActiveDataProvider you created to get the (filtered) data.

Comment: Hi Nicholas - I have updated the question as per ur suggestion, but I am getting the error as mentioned in the question.

Comment: Uh, yeah because it should _probably_ be `foreach($copyOfADP->getModels() as $i => $model)` or similar. See also [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-data-activedataprovider.html) and [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-output-data-providers.html).

Comment: Thanks - That error is gone, but I am getting another error in the `$command` line - `yii\base\ErrorException - Array to string conversion`

Comment: Ok I have created a variable - `$implode=implode(',',$ids);` and replaced that in the query, now I am getting the sum correctly, but the sum is not getting updated on filter or search.

Comment: I fixed my code sample as well now. The ActiveDataProvider is useless (kind of), because it contains paginated data, which you don't want in this case.
Additionally you need to update the query (as explained in the new comment) when the GridView DataProvider is updated as well. The same parameters need to be passed. You should probably take a look at EstimateSearch model (assuming it exists and is used in this context).

Comment: Yes EstimateSearch do exist. But I am still getting the full sum instead of filtered sum. Filters and search is based on Estimate Search. Where it can go wrong?

Comment: Well, the short answer is "I don't know" (because I don't actually have access to your code). The slightly longer answer is: you should probably use something like: `$searchModel = new EstimateSearch(); $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams); foreach($dataProvider->getModels() as $i => $model) { /*...*/ }`.

Comment: Your last suggestion worked just perfect. Many Thanks.